# WSL on win11 - Permission denied running python script

Tags: 20.04, permissions, python, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a python script that creates a file.
when running I get :

```
File "/home/ashi/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:"/Users"
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 using WSL on win11. I installed python using pyenv.
I have tried all the chmod commands, and tried from root user.

Thanks

Comment: `/Users`? Sounds like a macOS path. What frankensystem are you using that uses macOS paths in a Linux subsystem in Windows?

Comment: I have no idea. The only things I installed are pyenv - python 3.8.5, poetry - poetry install.

Comment: What's the actual command you're running that causes this problem? Is this script written by you or someone else?

Comment: The command I'm running is: python -m unittest test.test_contract

Comment: It wasn't written by me

Comment: Thanks guys! In the end it was caused because of one of the env variables.

Comment: @Ashi234 Good to hear you got it figured out.  It might be something that someone else will come across in the future, so it would be great if you could provide the details in an answer, then self-accept it.  This will also "close out" the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The problem was caused by an environment variable loaded from my `.envrc` file.
To solve the problem I just created the dir that the program was expecting to see.